# Powershell Ultimate Delete Directory

Tags: powershell, delete-directory

I have been struggling a bit with a cleanup script we have running on user home directories.  It is SUPPOSED to delete user folders for employees who no longer work here.

The users are not always smart so I have a large list of potential issues and am looking for the fastest way to delete this users folders.

Issues so far:

- ReparsePoints/Junction Points - I need them removed, but not followed... would hate to delete something the user linked to for some stupid reason
- Long Path Length - Some users have magically created path lengths that are way too long
- Need to be able to perform this delete remotely - The techs that will be running this script do not have permission to log directly onto the server, however they have full admin on the locations in question

Attempts so far:

```
robocopy "c:\temp\empty" $d.FullName /MIR /R:3 /W:1

remove-item $d.FullName -recurse -force
```

It should be noted I have tried with both UNC and mounted drive letters.

So all that to say I ask you, the brilliant folks of the web.  What is the best way to delete a folder, regardless of its content, length or links?

Thanks for any hints or help you can provide

Comment: I'd recommed [AlphaFS](http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com/) library. It's free, works correctly with NTFS junctions, symbolic links and long paths and is well-documented.

Comment: great suggestion, unfortunately I have to accomplish this with vanilla PowerShell.... long story

Comment: Then you're in a world of pain because .NET doesn't work with long file paths. One way or another you'll have to use Win32 API. The easiest and the least bumpy way is probably to rip the pieces you need from AlphaFS anyway (should be OK under MIT license) and add them as raw C# classes with Add-Type.

Comment: The length I can deal with by mapping a deeper chunk to a drive letter.  I am not sure I am good enough to go through that code and find the parts I need and use them properly